# JPasswordField that masks only part of an input

Tags: java, swing, jpasswordfield

I want to make component like JPasswordField that masks only part of an input, for example, for input 123456789, 12345**** will be rendered. I think that only correct way to do this is to override drawSelectedText() and drawUnselectedText() in component's View, but the problem with this approach is that I have to use TextUI from concrete look and feel (BasicPasswordFieldUI from AlexR's example) which might not work correctly when using some other lnf.

My problem is similar like one specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810777/rendering-java-jpasswordfield)

Any ideas on this? Is there some alternative to JTextField/JPasswordField that is more suitable for this job?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered having the JPasswordField and then having a TextField underneath with the partially masked input? You could render the mask as part of an action listener, say a button that says (verify input) which then masks the input and displays it in the text field.

Comment: Get the [JPasswordField source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JPasswordField.java) and modify it to display as you wish.